I want to run specific line in a .js file, how to make it right?
source js file:
text
I just want to run this line:
var Jk = JN['V'](this['Y'][0xced + 0x83 * 0x4a + -0x32ca])
, Jk = Ja[Fh(bc.F)](Jw, Jk, JQ);
and I know "this['Y'][0xced + 0x83 * 0x4a + -0x32ca]" refer to string "/portal/main/flight/direct/query"
how to run it in python ? (selenium or whatever can make it right)

I tried selenium, use "execute_script" to run the whole file, then add "var Jk = JN['V'](this['Y'][0xced + 0x83 * 0x4a + -0x32ca])
, Jk = Ja[Fh(bc.F)](Jw, Jk, JQ);", get an error, said "no JN blabla"

execute_script will have its own scope.  If you want to use those variables, you need to include the bits of the script that define them in the string you send to execute_script.  (or retrieve them if they are stored somewhere in global state/storage...)
